Unexpected control flow in this Python code with Matplotlib
This Python 3.12 code on Ubuntu 22.04 behaves as expected, except when I press q or ESC key to quit. Here is the code:
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path
from collections import namedtuple
from skimage.io import imread
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider


def update(u):
  global minR, minG, minB

  minR = sliderR.val
  minG = sliderG.val
  minB = sliderB.val

  axImg.imshow(img)
  plt.title(f'iFile {iFile}/{len(files)-1}')
  plt.show() #----------------------------------------- step 3


def onpress(event):
  global files, iFile, iStart, iEnd, img

  match event.key:
    case 'q' | 'escape':
      plt.close() #------------------------------------- step 1
      return #------------------------------------------ step 2
    case 'pageup' | 'pagedown' as incr:
      if incr == 'pagedown':
        iFile = min(iFile+1, len(files)-1)
      else:
        iFile = max(iFile-1, 0)
    case 'o':
      path = Path('/home/paul/downloads/fig-0.png')
      files = [f for f in Path(path.parent).glob('*.png')]
      files.sort()
      iFile = files.index(path)
      iStart, iEnd = 0, np.inf

  img = imread(files[iFile])
  update(None)


nRows, nCols = 20, 15
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 14))
axImg = plt.subplot2grid((nRows, nCols), (0, 0), rowspan=nRows-4, colspan=nCols)
axR = plt.subplot2grid((nRows, nCols), (nRows-3, 1), colspan=nCols-2)
axG = plt.subplot2grid((nRows, nCols), (nRows-2, 1), colspan=nCols-2)
axB = plt.subplot2grid((nRows, nCols), (nRows-1, 1), colspan=nCols-2)
sliderR = Slider(ax=axR, label='R', valmin=0, valmax=255, valinit=128, valstep=4) 
sliderG = Slider(ax=axG, label='G', valmin=0, valmax=255, valinit=128, valstep=4) 
sliderB = Slider(ax=axB, label='B', valmin=0, valmax=255, valinit=128, valstep=4) 
sliderR.on_changed(update)
sliderG.on_changed(update)
sliderB.on_changed(update)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', onpress)
plt.get_current_fig_manager().full_screen_toggle()
onpress(namedtuple('T', ['key'])('o')) #------------------- step 4

When I set a breakpoint at step 1, start debugging with VS Code and press q or ESC key, the control goes to step 1, step 2 and then, unexpectedly, to step 3 and step 4. I expected 1, 2 and 4 sequence.

I think that Matplotlib's event loop resides in plt.show() and that's why the control goes back to it in step 3.
